# How can I have no bold in summation?

Tags: bold

I had pass an algorithm with a lot of summations (Σ) in a `.tex` file using `amsmath` and everything was OK, now I have include this file with the appropriate transformation in the preamble of my thesis using the template `classicthesis` and all the signs of summation (Σ) are in bold. I'm really not sure what is going wrong and I can't find any answer that can help. I hope that someone will have a suggestion, thanks in advance!

Here is an example. For the preamble:

```
    % book example for classicthesis.sty
     \documentclass[
    % Replace twoside with oneside if you are printing your thesis on a single side
     % of the paper, or for viewing on screen.
     %oneside,
     oneside,
      11pt, a4paper,
     footinclude=true,
     headinclude=true,
      cleardoublepage=empty
     ]{scrbook}


      \setlength{\parindent}{4em}

      \usepackage{lipsum}
       \usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
        \usepackage{amsmath}


       \usepackage{acronym}
        \usepackage{graphicx}
         \usepackage{hyperref}
        \hypersetup{
           colorlinks,
        citecolor=black,
         filecolor=black,
       linkcolor=black,
        urlcolor=black
            }
     \usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}
     \usepackage{multirow}
     \usepackage{keyval}
     \usepackage{colortbl}
     \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{csquotes}
   \usepackage{fancybox}
    \usepackage{varwidth}
       \usepackage{parskip}
    \usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
     \usepackage{tocloft}
    \usepackage{minitoc}
    \usepackage{mathptmx}
   \usepackage{setspace}

    \usepackage{bbding}
   \usepackage{pifont}
    \usepackage{wasysym}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}

      \renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}%
       \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{LIST OF FIGURES}%
       \renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont}

          \setlength{\cftbeforefigskip}{0.2in}
       \renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont}
       \renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}


    \renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
    \renewcommand{\cftsubsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
    \renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
    \renewcommand{\cftfigleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
    \renewcommand{\cfttableader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}







        \title{A Sample Thesis} 
       \author{A.N. Other} 
         \date{July 2013} 
         \titlehead{A Thesis submitted for the degree of Doctor of Philosophy} 
        \setlength{\parindent}{4em} 
       \begin{document} 
              \maketitle 
           \frontmatter
       \tableofcontents
        \listoffigures 
        \listoftables 


          \chapter{Acknowledgements} 

         I would like to thank my supervisor, Professor Someone. This 
         research was funded by the Imaginary Research Council. 

        \chapter{Abstract} 

        A brief summary of the project goes here. 

        \chapter{Abbreviations}

       \mainmatter 

      \include{tool}

          \backmatter  

      \begin{thebibliography}{100} % 100 is a random guess of the total number of 
       %references 




       \end{thebibliography}



       \end{document}
```

And for the tool.tex:

```
  \chapter{Design of Decision Support Models}
   \label{ch:problem}
   \section {Target of the project}



    \section{Description of the Model}
       \subsection{VAP basic model}





         \begin{align}
     \min \quad
       & \sum_{t=0}^{T} \sum_{i\in N}\sum_{j\in N,i \neq j} f_{ij}x_{ijt}+p_{ki}y_{ki}
     \end{align}

    Subject to: 
       \begin{align}
        \sum_{j \in N}(x_{ijt}+y_{ijt})-\sum_{k \in N, k\neq i,t \geq \tau_{ki}}                   (x_{ki(t-\tau_{ki})}+y_{ki(t-\tau_{ki})})- y{iit-1}-m_{it}+y_{iit} =0&& \forall (i,t)
        \end{align}
   \begin{center}
    \begin{align}
      x_{ijt}\geq d_{ijt}&& i \in N, j \in N, t \in {0,...,T}\\
      x_{ijt} \geq 0&& i \in N, j \in N, t \in {0,...,T}\\
      y_{ijt} \geq 0&& i \in N, j \in N, t \in {0,...,T}
     \end{align}
        \end{center}
```

Comment: please provide a small compliable example that illustrates the problem.  `amsmath` doesn't make math bold by itself, so it has to be explicitly requested.  and ordinarily, the computer modern fonts don't even *have* a bold summation sign, so i suspect that some other font, with a differently designed, summation, is involved.

Comment: Please make your example code smaller. You can copy the file to a new name and comment some lines which seem irrelevant to the error. If you find the minimal set of lines that produces the error you can remove all other lines and post it above.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with `classicthesis`. It's `mathptmx` that uses a pretty heavy symbol.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Do you know if I can use another package instead of the mathptmx ? If i delete it the sum indeed looks better (not ideal though) but the whole document is transformed,images and tables change position and a lot of blank pages appear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this example can be reduced to the following:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\begin{document}
\[ \sum \]
\end{document}
```

in fact, it could probably be reduced further, but for this demonstration, it's not worth the effort.  the result of processing this is the following:

[image: sum using mathptx fonts]

this is the sum as provided by the `mathptmx` package.  comment out that package, and this is what you get:

[image: sum using mathpazo fonts]

looking at the log, we find that the `mathpazo` package is loaded by `classicthesis.sty`, so this is the sum from the `mathpazo` fonts.

we can compare these to the familiar computer modern sum by requesting that using `article.cls` with no additional packages:

[image: sum from computer modern fonts]

so what you see as "bold" is the difference in the design of the symbol.
it's generally recommended to stick with symbol fonts that are "compatible" with
the main text font.  besides, it's a pain (though possible) to substitute single symbols
from a different font, so you are better off sticking with what you have, since the
style really is more compatible than most other options, even if you don't really like it.

Comment: thanks for your answer, as I can understand is not easy to change it and probably will need to change the  classicthesis.sty. Removing  the  mathptmx  package it was indeed looking better but still was not the desirable.